# CCCallFunc in Cocos2d-x with a sub-class

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I have this CCCallFunc being constructed

```
CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(STLoadingSceneBase::load1))
```

But what I really need to call is load1(...) on STLoadingSceneSubClass, a subclass of STLoadingSceneBase. My goal is to create one set of CCCallFunc in the super-class and have the callbacks fired in the sub-class.

Is there a way to use callfunc_selector with "this" that I'm missing?

I tried this but it didn't work

```
CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(this::load1))
```

Comment: You can use lambda function as the parameter of `CCCallFunc::create()`, and use `this` inside the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried callfunc_selector(STLoadingSceneSubClass::load1)?

Comment: That works if the callfunc_selector is used from the sub-class but doesn't actually allow the super-class to schedule calls to virtual methods. :(